# Randomly Generate Points in a Spiral Motion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

So I have a javascript program that currently gets random points, it generates a random x,y,z value around the center point, within the radius `r`

```
  var maxArms = 3;
  var i = 0;
    var color = [];
  for(var arm = 0; arm <= maxArms; arm++) {
    var perArm = (numStars/maxArms);
    var perPoint = Math.ceil((r/10)/5);
    var actualPoints = ((r/10)/5);
    perPoint = (perArm/(actualPoints+(actualPoints/4)));
    var angle = 8;

    for (var ra = 0; ra < 412; ra += 2) {
        for (var p = 0; p < (580-ra); p++) {
        var an = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        var pX = x(ra,angle) + ((Math.cos(an) * (Math.random()*512)) * (Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1)), 
                pY = y(ra,angle) + ((Math.cos(an) * (Math.random()*512)) * (Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1)),
            pZ = Math.random() * ((r/2)-p) * (1 / ra) * (Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1),
                particle = new THREE.Vertex(
                    new THREE.Vector3(pX, pZ, pY)
                );
            innerRing.vertices.push(particle);

            var h = Math.random() * (291 - 185) + 185,
                s = Math.random() * (66 - 34) + 34,
                v = Math.random() * (100 - 72) + 72;
            color[i] = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
            color[i].setHSV(h / 360, s / 100, v / 100);

        i++;
        }
    }
  }
```

Now I am trying to find a way rather than just randomly placing things anywhere within the radius, to spiral out the points, into a defined number of "Spiral Arms", I am sure this is going to require something with Sine and Cosine, but I have spent hours now looking to understand how to use these functions to do what I need and I am not sure how to do it.

What I am looking for is I want a variable for the number of arms `numArms` and I want to have the function above take the number of arms, and create an equal number of points in each arm, and each arm  arc out from the center point `0,0` in a spiral motion.

Does that make sense?

I have found other questions, and different answers with google about how to make a spiral, as well as how to find random points (as shown above) but nothing that can help me find random points around spiral arms, but once I have the points for the spiral I am not sure how to get the random x,y,z coordinates around the spiral.

Also, if it is possible, to make it so towards the beginning of each arm there are more points than at the end of the arm.

Yes I know my script is not properly optimized, but I am looking more for function at the moment.

I have attached an image of what the currently generated with the code below, as well as a sample of a spiral galaxy, althought I do not want the center as huge as the second image.

---

**Edit**

I have made some changes to the generation script, although rather sloppy, it starts out making stars come from the middle like a spiral, but it inevitably gets larger and no longer looks like a spiral, I have tried playing with all of the variables (`ra` and `angle`) but it does not make the spiral look any better, what can I do?

Current Generation:

[image]

Sample Generation:

[image]

Comment: Do you want something like a Milky Way galaxy shape? Are the spiral arms meant to be different in their general shape?

Comment: Sort of, it will vary by the number of arms what the shape is, but if I provided it say 6 arms, it would look generally like the milky way.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin the above response was to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you just need to follow the formula for a **spiral**, given as,

```
 x(t) = a * t * cos(t), y(t) = a * t * sin(t)
```

where `a` is constant you can use to express how fast your **spiral** expands. For the 3D case just add the extra argument `z`. To define a number of arms, you could just place this inside another `for` statement. However, if don't want to create a growing 3D spiral, you could fix the `z` parameter within a certain range. To create the illusion of a galaxy, I believe you could add an offset to `x` and `y` and run it multiple times,

```
var a = 5;
var offset = 2; // You have to choose a good offset for your project.

var numArms = 3;
for (var arm; arm < numArms; arm++) {
    for (var p = 0; p < num; p++) {
        var pX = a * p * cos(p + (Math.PI * arm)) + (Math.random() * offset);
        var pY = a * p * sin(p + (Math.PI * arm)) + (Math.random() * offset);
        var pZ = Math.random() * a;   

        // do something with pX, pY, and pZ
    }
}
```

Look in here for the [original **spiral** formulas](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spiral.htm), and to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874678/looping-through-a-formula-that-describes-a-spiral-to-generate-xy-coordinates), which does something similar using `PHP`.

Comment: I do not understand what your 3D Case is doing, it does not appear like it would create random placement of anything along the points of the spiral, you would just have a single point at each point in the spiral, the problem I am having is creating the random points along the spiral, not creating the spiral itself, I have seen the question you linked to before, and I understand what it is saying, I can create the spiral shape itself, but I cannot figure out how to add random x,y,z coordinates around the shape of the spiral.

Comment: Can you give a better description of your intentions (a picture or a drawing preferably), because adding random points will effectively destroy the spiral.

Comment: I have attached 2 links to images, one displays the current output of my above script, the second displays a sample of a spiral based galaxy with random points around the spiral points.

Comment: Based on the images you posted, you don't a 3D version, but rather a 2D version with some third dimensional offsets (like in a galaxy), which you can achieve by setting `pZ` to random numbers within a range. For the different arms you can add a `PI` offset to `p` inside the `cos` and `sin` functions.

Comment: This did not work the way I am trying to get it to work.

Comment: The script you gave me when I plugged it in to my existing code just created multiple spiral arms, but all with a single "star" at each point, the single star arms would then wrap around and around thousands of times but getting infinitely further apart and going higher up into the axis, the original script kept everything within a certain depth, and just added more stars to the center of the system, now I just need to make the stars follow a path rather than just being completely random.

Comment: Also the reason I am doing it 3d is because I am generating this using three.js and it requires an X,Y and Z position because the entire view can me zoomed in, twisted, and viewed from different angles, which is why I am doing it this way rather than doing an image.

Comment: You can control how big the **spiral** gets by manipulating `a` and `num`, to keep it within a certain depth. The `z` parameter you can randomized within a range applicable to your project like I mentioned. To get the `stars` you can run the same code multiple times but with different `random` offsets, every time positioning a `star` at a random place along the **spiral**. I don't have a way to test it to provide you with a more accurate implementation, but I hope this bit will get you there.

Comment: Attached image of current generation.

Comment: You don't seem to be adapting the `a`, `offset` and `num` values as indicated. That's why you're getting such an extensive spread. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Updated the script in question. If you want to run it yourself you will  need `three.js` and `jquery`

Comment: I can't run this without the `HTML` and the images; however, I see that `r` controls most of the offsetting, and it's quite large. Try reducing it, and trying different values to achieve the result you need.

Comment: I believe what I am attempting to do may just not be possible, or I am just not at a skill to do what I need, I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't give up. Take a break and try again in the morning. If it seems simpler, try the 2D case first (set `z = 0`) to see if you can achieve something without worrying about 3D. By the picture, it seems like you're close, except the `offset` is too large and so the stars seem to far apart. You've got it... is it just a matter of multiplying by the right value (a smaller one in this case).

Comment: Also, by looking at the image, I see close to 40 arms. Try reducing that number as it may affect how it looks when compressed (making it look like a circle, rather than a **spiral**).

Comment: The `numArms` variable was set to 4 when I ran the script, also the `r` variable is set to a number that is supposed to define the limit for how far away from the center point the stars are allowed to spawn, as well as how deep the star field goes.

Comment: I have added an update, I couldn't lay it to rest, it is looking better, maybe you can look at my spiral generation and explain why it starts to lose the spiral shape?

Comment: I believe it is because the single cluster of stars is getting wider and wider and when combined with the other arms starts to look like concentric circles. I would restrict `ra` a bit more (make it smaller).

Comment: But isn't `ra` what is making the spiral longer? I need the spiral to continue growing, but stay close to eachother.

Comment: rae1n and @Cory. Please take this discussion to [chat]. Then come back and incorporate any useful information into the answer so we can clean up these comments.

Comment: @ChrisF it says I do not have enough reputation for the chat.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on the previous answer to add some randomisation to it

```
a = 15
r = sqrt(random())* max radius
x = a * r * cos(r) + (2 * a * random() - a)
y = a * r * sin(r) + (2 * a * random() - a)
```

by using the square root of the random number you get proportionally more points in the outer edge of the spiral this give the illusion of a more random placement

then with x and y being displaced by random fraction of the "a" modifier the points are no longer precisely on the spiral